# Growth of products of polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

I just came across the following problem, which I didn't manage to solve:

Suppose you are given a polynomial $P=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_0\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ such that $a_i\geq 0$ for $i=1,\dots,n$, $a_0=0$ and $a_n\leq 1$. Is it true that there exist constants $C, M>0$ such that for all $l\geq 1$ and $x_1,\dots, x_l\geq 0$

$$
\prod_{i=1}^lP(x_i)\leq C(x_1+\cdots +x_l)^M.
$$

In particular, $C$ and $M$ should be independent of $l$. I tried an induction on the degree of the polynomial, which is trivial in degree $1$, but I couldn't proceed in the induction step. Neither could I produce a counterexample.

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: Suppose there exists such $C,M$ for $P(x)= x.$ Take all  $x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_l=x.$ Then $x^l\le C(lx)^M$ for all $l\in \mathbb N$ and all $x\ge 0.$ That is impossible if $l>M.$

Comment: Thanks! I missed that point...